# Has any Western leader articulated how NATO would benefit from admitting Ukraine?

Tags: military, ukraine, nato

NATO sees itself as a defensive alliance, so its members are expected to benefit from banding together and deterring attacks.

No doubt Ukraine would greatly benefit from membership in its recurring disputes with Russia.

However, besides principles like *we stand up for freedom and democracy*, have any Western leaders articulated what the **existing** NATO members gain?

Part of this process was [somewhat started in 2008](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/11/30/world/europe/30iht-nato.4.18268641.html), as a result of a compromise between the US and European countries where it was penciled in at a deliberately indeterminate future.

NATO, can, and should, assist Ukraine in maintaining its territorial sovereignty.  Deliberately taking on the responsibility of automatically being drawn into a shooting war should it happen, however is another thing.

For reference, this is what the [UK Defense Secretary had to say](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-59712020) recently, implying that NATO troops would have had to be committed if Ukraine was part of NATO.

> In an interview with the Spectator, Mr Wallace said Ukraine was "not a member of Nato, so it is highly unlikely that anyone is going to send troops into Ukraine to challenge Russia".

**Have any Western or NATO officials explained the rationale for an eventual accession?**

NATO's secretary general [has said](https://www.euractiv.com/section/defence-and-security/news/russia-has-no-right-to-establish-a-sphere-of-influence-nato-chief-says/):

> Asked in Riga about Putin’s statements and Ukraine’s potential future membership, Stoltenberg said Ukraine’s membership in NATO will be decided by its 30 members, provided that this country meets the relevant criteria, including reform of institutions and the fight against corruption.

> “Russia has no veto. Russia has no say. And Russia has no right to establish a sphere of influence, trying to control their neighbours,”

Stating that it is not Russia's right to veto someone else's decision is indeed correct.  But that is not the same thing as showing a compelling reason **for** NATO to take on this responsibility.

Russia, for all its often fraught relations with its neighbors, does have valid security concerns about NATO showing up on its doorstep (the Baltics are so small that they have limited strategic depth as a NATO base).  Even if its current demands are [maximalist](https://www.reuters.com/world/russia-unveils-security-guarantees-says-western-response-not-encouraging-2021-12-17/) and given in a context where few NATO countries trust Russia.

And if you want to look at how well-intentioned defensive alliances can end up triggering wars, you need look no further than the start of WW1 where basically everyone was committed to one of two alliance blocs and things quickly escalated from a minor incident.

To look at things from the Russian perspective, how would say the US feel if Mexico got into a defense pact with China?  Too speculative you say?  Well, then look at the US's concerns about Cuba during the Cold War.

So, where's the beef?  Have any senior leaders or officials communicated what NATO ( the US, Canada and its European constituents) **gain** from taking on Ukraine?  As opposed to say merely assisting Ukraine in acquiring defensive weapons and drawing a line in the sand with regards to economic sanctions.  Which is... where we are at right now.

**It seems like that level of foreign policy commitment would need extensive justification of the pros and cons to the electorate of the countries taking on that role.  Not just platitudes about democracy.  Has this taken place?**

To be clear:  I am not looking for military reasons that could motivate admitting Ukraine, I am looking for *leaders and senior officials, speaking in an official capacity, making statements about those reasons on the record.*

(FWIW it seems to me that admission is unlikely in the future, the same way Turkey's request to join the EU was held in permanent limbo, before Erdogan made it unpalatable to everyone else.  But like with Turkey, no one's quite willing to call a cat a cat)

Comment: Ukraine has a large military, so that might be it. I'll need to do some more research before answering though.

Comment: If Ukraine has no Russian military positioned on its territory, then Ukraine serves as a large buffer against a possibly anti-NATO Russian regime. Plus, what Ekadh said above.

Comment: @TimurShtatland Even a neutral country provides a buffer between antagonists.  Ukraine does not need to be in NATO to fulfill that role and its troops would be available too if Russian troops came in.  Plus Ukraine's army is probably very limited in projecting force out of theatre - i.e. they are "useful" to NATO *in Ukraine*, but unlikely to be a worthwhile aid elsewhere.

Comment: The point of NATO is that an enemy (OK, Russia) cannot pick off the European nations one by one, because each is obligated to defend the others. Including Ukraine in this would be telling Russia that an attack on Ukraine would be met with a massive military response in its defence. The hope is that this would deter Russia from attacking Ukraine. This would also gain for NATO a substantial ally against Russia, and since Ukraine would have to commit to certain reforms in order to join NATO, move Ukraine further into the Western camp.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that NATO is an anti-Russian alliance, for which it's obviously beneficial to have an ally that borders the enemy country. I doubt any NATO official will actually say that in public, though.

Comment: Just to be clear here, because of all this "we can now be based close to them".  That is very much a bug, not a feature, of this.  It creates a flashpoint risk and it brings not all that much benefit as it would also force NATO troops to defend at the limit of long logistical lines for them, and short ones for Russia.  At the same it would make Russia more paranoid.

Comment: @Allure - Secretary General Jens Stoltenberg came awfully close to saying exactly that in a [recent speech](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/opinions_188772.htm?selectedLocale=en): "Germany can, of course, decide whether there will be nuclear weapons in your country, but the alternative is that we easily end up with nuclear weapons in other countries in Europe, also to the east of Germany"  (quote from the SecGen's answer to a question from Paul Krüger)

Comment: @PeteW I wouldn't read that much into that sentence. Multiple European countries west of Germany already have some nukes but no countries east of Germany do. If the nukes can't be in Germany, then obviously it's fairly likely they'll go to one of its eastern neighbours.

Comment: @TooTea -- Oh it's pretty close to a direct implication, if you examine the context. The subject of the speech is whether it is appropriate for Germany (who has no nukes) to continue to host nukes from other NATO members. The quote is from the answer to a question asked by a member of the press, about whether an particular [NATO-Russia agreement](https://www.nato.int/nrc-website/media/59451/1997_nato_russia_founding_act.pdf) is "still valid", and this agreement includes not keeping nukes too close.

Comment: Some Polish and Lithuanian statements associated with the signing of the **Lublin Triangle agreement**  come close to answering this question. This agreement specifically calls for said accession.

Comment: @Allure *obviously beneficial to have an ally that borders the enemy country.*  I beg to differ.  If you are trying to attack the enemy, yes, it is beneficial.  If you are trying to avoid giving the enemy easy logistics to work with then it is not and that's before taking into account the risk of accidental flashpoints.  The benefit or penalty is asymmetric depending on your offense/defense posture, not constant as you claim.  Related:  Taiwan/SK hosting so much of the West's semiconductor industry, so close to China and the difficulty of defending Taiwan.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I don't understand what you mean by "constant"? Furthermore, even if you aren't planning to attack, you can still deploy your weapons closer to the border. Also, I don't think Taiwan/SK are "hosting" the West's semiconductor industry, TSMC and Samsung are indigenous companies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As a partial answer, not specific to the Ukraine -- here is a 1999 CRS report from on the subject of NATO expansion to former Eastern-bloc countries. It includes a summary of the Clinton Administration's position. This covers the time period in the mid 1990s when the arrangements were made to get the first cohort of former Soviet-bloc countries into NATO.

[NATO: Congress Addresses
Expansion of the Alliance [Congressional Research Service, 1999]](https://www.everycrsreport.com/files/19990524_RL30192_c9adab6ad1b595a94d0196df7cc4e54710bb28e1.pdf)

Benefits cited for NATO expansion included

- fostering economic integration into the western business world
- preventing ethno-national tensions
- preventing nuclear proliferation
- enhancing stability in Europe

On the question of NATO vs Russia, a mixture of positions is taken. On the one hand, the report states

> In 1991, NATO declared that the (then) Soviet Union was no longer an
> “enemy” of NATO. In NATO’s 1991 “Strategic Concept”, the alliance
> signaled its intention to move towards lighter, more mobile forces for
> power projection in central Europe to develop an improved capability
> for crisis management and such missions as peacekeeping and peace
> enforcement.

On the other hand, the report quickly follows this by citing a concern about long-term re-emergence of Russia as a power

> NATO’s mission of collective defense remains important to member
> states because of a concern that Russia, still armed with nuclear
> weapons, might one day become more unstable and aggressive, and a
> direct threat to its neighbors. Representatives of several central
> European states interviewed recently expressed concern over an
> eventual Russian threat, and stated that the Article V commitment is
> the principal reason for their desire to join the alliance.

According to the report, opinions by existing NATO member states  varied (and support depended on the country being considered).

> The European allies evince a spectrum of views on the issue of
> enlargement. At the Madrid summit, a consensus settled on naming
> Poland, the Czech Republic, and Hungary as candidate states. In the
> summit communiqué, the allies agreed that enlargement would enhance
> stability
>
> ...
>
> Elements of doubt about enlargement and its effect on strategic issues
> remain evident. These sentiments will affect possible future rounds of
> enlargement. Some officials in NATO countries believe that different
> security interests [in NATO] are being regionalized, with the
> implication that the addition of more states would lead to further
> dilution of consensus in the alliance
>
> ...
>
> Allied governments were reluctant to share in the costs of
> enlargement as initially estimated by the Clinton Administration ...

---

Additional Background for Research:

One figure who seems central within the Clinton Administration's push to realize the 1990s NATO expansion was Deputy Secretary of State [Strobe Talbott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strobe_Talbott), who shortly after became president of Brookings (think tank, and a cornerstone of the US foreign policy world).

On the subject at hand, Talbott published a NY Review of Books piece promoting the NATO expansion: [Why NATO Should Grow](https://www.nybooks.com/articles/1995/08/10/why-nato-should-grow/) (paywalled). Several rebuttals were published in response by US policy figures, such as [Should NATO Grow? A Dissent](https://www.nybooks.com/articles/1995/09/21/should-nato-growa-dissent/), which make for interesting reading today.

Published memos between Talbott and Clinton, regarding Clinton's interactions with the Russian government of the time might also be of interest. Talbott did wish to bring Ukraine into NATO as well, in the same mid-late 1990s period.

Comment: +1 This is the kind of thing I am looking for, but it dates from a long time ago and doesn't concern Ukraine, but rather *Poland, Hungary, the Czech Republic, and Slovakia*.   Do we have anything recent, covering Ukraine.  Which frankly is very different in nature, geography and proximity to Russia, from central European countries which were never in the Russian sphere of influence to start with (or should not have been).  Well, except in as far as Talbott wanted Ukraine too.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica the four bullet points listed in this answer are also 100% valid for the current case of Ukraine. Economic integration? Without russian troops in Ukraine and Ukraine in NATO, the stability of western economic activities in Ukraine is much higher. Ethno-national tensions? Without russian meddling Ukraine integrates much more with Europe and as a result there is less tensions. Nuclear proliferation? There is a real risk that without NATO support, Ukraine might some day pursue nuclear weapons. Stability? You say there would be less, because of possible flashpoints...

Comment: ...but actually there could be more stability. Russia would be less willing to risk it all and would have to simply accept that its sphere of influence has completely eroded and there is nothing to gain.

Comment: Accepting.  Not at all convinced by the arguments being made, but my question was not about that, merely asking who had made what arguments.  But I can't help but notice that our policy towards Ukraine acceptance is being driven by a set of 20 year old arguments made by a long-past Deputy Sec of State, with little modern reassessment.  Just a remark, not a criticism of your answer.

Comment: @ciamej For ethno-national tensions NATO membership would not be so good, as the bigest minority in Ukraine are russian.

Comment: @convert Maybe, or maybe not... There's a large russian minority in Latvia and they benefit greatly from EU integration. I'm not saying there are no tensions in Latvia, just that they are dwarfed by economic benefits (to the russian community itself).

Comment: @ciamej It´s hard to say if they really profit, since they have not much rights in the country. Also EU is not the same as NATO even if most EU countries, including Baltic states, are NATO members.

Comment: @convert Yes, NATO alone does not matter that much, but in context of Ukraine we're talking about integration with the west in general - being a NATO member, and having one's borders secure makes it much easier to integrate economically, including joining EU.

Comment: With regard to russians in Latvia, they _do_ participate in economy. The economy of Latvia would look much different if occupied by Russia - just take a look at Abkhazia, Transnistria, or Crimea to imagine how well off would Latvians be (and the russian community in Latvia) if under russian rule (or influence). Many russians run successful bussinesses in Latvia, so it's hard to say they are really suppressed economically. Politically maybe, but not economically.

Comment: @ciamej Finland is an example, that what you say don´t have to be true. Finland was integrated with the West even befor becoming EU member and it was in very similar situation then Ukraine.

Comment: @convert I agree that it is not necessary to join NATO or even EU to integrate with the west, but I think that Ukraine's odds to successfully integrate are much higher without the constant threat of an armed invasion and on-going partial occupation... NATO seems to help its members with such issues, at least a little bit ;)

Comment: @ciamej I explecitly took the example of Finland, as it was in very similar situation and without joining the NATO it has seen no russian invasion since more then 80 years. Should not forget that the reason for the conflict between Russia and Ukraine was exactly the posible membership of Ukraine in NATO.

Comment: @convert I wouldn't say that the possible membership was the _reason_, but rather a _pretext_. The real reason was the ongoing integration with the west. Finland had a bloody war with Soviet Union, and the only reason there were no further attempts to invade Finland, was because of Finland's resistance and competence in the defence war, along with its natural geography making the invasion difficult. Nothing that Ukraine has now. Moreover, Finland actually gave up much of its land to the Soviet Union, so it's not like there were no concessions.

Comment: @ciamej Russia was never hapy about ongoing integration of Ukraine with the west, but it is not a reason for invasion, as this integration started already 2004, which would be a much easier time point for invasion.

Comment: @convert Perhaps, in 2004 Putin thought that the shift towards the west was reversible (as it later happened with Janukovych reelection) so no military intervention was needed. Then, maybe the calculations changed, and Putin believed that without military intervention the integration with the west was unavoidable. We don't know. Nonetheless, the fact there was no invastion in 2004 does not mean, that later invasion was not prompted by the prospects of further integration with the west (and away from Russia's sphere of influence).

Comment: @ciamej It´s wrong to say that Janukovych was a pro russian presiden, he was just les anti russian then the previous president. That EU asociation thing started during he was president. For stoping or at least making harder Ukrains integration in to West, Russia didn´t need to invade Ukraine, some economic sanctions would do the job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133751/discussion-between-ciamej-and-convert).

Answer (score 6):

The US (which effectively covers all other NATO countries under its nuclear umbrella): 1) wants influence in European affairs and 2) wants to show that they and NATO have credibility, and 3) wants to deter Russian aggression.

> As with unipolarity and power maximization, there is something to the logic
> of credibility, prestige, and leadership as drivers of the enlargement consensus. It
> is certainly true that US policymakers in the early 1990s viewed enlargement as a
> way of counteracting perceived drift in US grand strategy (Chollett and Goldgeier
> 2008). Bush and his team, for instance, regularly emphasized to domestic and foreign audiences that the United States was wedded to post-Cold War engagement via
> NATO (Engel 2017, 280, 305, 350–355; Schake 1998, 379–407). Similarly, work
> by James Goldgeier, Ronald Asmus, and others highlights that many enlargement
> proponents on Clinton’s team treated expansion as a way of underscoring the United
> States’ resolve in structuring post-Cold War European security afairs. Furthermore, both the George W. Bush and Barack Obama administrations highlighted that
> NATO represented what Bush termed the United States’ commitment to ‘a close and
> permanent partnership with the nations of Europe,’ within which the United States
> supported ‘the enlargement of NATO’ because it equally embraced ‘a more united
> Europe’ (New York Times 2002; White House 2016).
>
> The argument also garners circumstantial support from the deliberations over
> expansion to include Georgia and Ukraine. When broached in the late 2000s, including Georgia and Ukraine in NATO was opposed by many of the United States’ European allies, fearful that doing so would antagonize Russia (Myers 2008). Despite this, the United States persistently pushed for a pledge that these states would eventually become NATO members (Rice 2011, 670–675). Concerns with NATO’s credibility and influence were at least a partial driver of this effort. As Bush recalled in his memoirs, ‘The threat from Russia strengthened the case for extending [membership plans] to Georgia and Ukraine. Russia would be less likely to engage in aggression if these countries were on a path into NATO’ (Bush 2010, 431). Nor was Bush alone in this; since 2008, a bevy of think tank and policy analysts have emphasized the desirability of keeping Georgian and Ukrainian membership a possibility lest NATO and US credibility suffer (Japaridze 2014; Daalder and Goldgeier 2008; Tobey 2014; Wilson and Kramer 2018).

Source: NATO enlargement and US foreign policy: the origins, durability, and impact of an idea. Shifrinson, Joshua R. *International Politics*; Basingstoke Vol. 57, Iss. 3,  (Jun 2020): 342-370. DOI:10.1057/s41311-020-00224-w

Answer (score 1):

The *exact* answer to your question may be hard to find. But as a proxy one could look at the recent material from the experts on Russia, Ukraine, or general military. Also note that since NATO is a military organization, most of the considerations related to your question would have military associations, by default. For example, here are a few ways in which NATO would benefit from admitting Ukraine.

- As a NATO member *vs.* a neutral country, the territory of Ukraine will become a buffer for the other NATO member countries against a possible Russian aggression, of the type that Russia threatens NATO members now (as of the time of this writing). As far as other NATO countries are concerned, a war on other country's territory may be more preferable that the war on the home ground.
- As a NATO country, Ukraine will provide additional closely allied and tightly linked military, with considerable manpower and equipment. The more people and weapons, the stronger is the alliance, this seems obvious. As they say, together we stand, divided we fall.
- Ukraine offers to NATO 7 years of experience in fighting the Russian regular army as well as the Russian-backed separatist units, all having the latest Russian military equipment. It is valuable to have a battle-tested army. Even better is to have an army tested in battles with a strong, aggressive adversary. Still better is to have an army tested under cold weather conditions (this is something NATO has very little experience with), for the future possible conflicts under the similarly cold or even colder conditions, for instance the Arctic (Peterson, 2021).

Western leaders and officials may be reluctant to speak openly of the above issues because these pragmatic considerations may appear to be less acceptable to the public than the (more emotional, but still valid) reasons that are mentioned more frequently. To the public, it may look better to cite the (also valid but more palatable) reasons for accepting Ukraine into NATO, such as to make NATO safer and more secure, promote the Western democratic ideals in Ukraine and Russia, support the ally in their hour of need, etc.

**REFERENCES:**

> The Arctic is rapidly becoming a strategic priority for the world’s trifecta of competing great powers — the United States, China, and Russia. This winter, the US Air Force sent B-1B supersonic bombers to Norway for war games, marking the first time that US bombers had ever deployed to the country (which shares a border with Russia). Likewise, US Marines have increased the frequency of their extreme cold weather training in Norway, and US Global Strike Command now routinely operates strategic bomber task force missions through Arctic airspace. Alaska, America’s northernmost territory, is today home to more advanced fighter jets than any other state.
>
> With that renewed Arctic focus in mind, the frigid winter battlefields in eastern Ukraine present the Pentagon with a case study in modern, extreme cold weather warfare.
>
> “During the seven years of war with Russia, we gained a lot of experience,” Alexander Pochynok, 41, a Ukrainian army sniper who fought at the Donetsk airport, told Coffee or Die Magazine.

*Nolan Peterson, March 13, 2021. Coffee or Die Magazine. Lessons in Winter Warfare From the Ukrainian War Zone — A Case Study for America’s Arctic: https://coffeeordie.com/lessons-winter-warfare/*

Comment: Turkey is in NATO.  Portugal co-founded NATO when it was still a military dictatorship.  So clearly, NATO has nothing to do with democracy or human rights; it was founded as an anti-communist military alliance and somehow redefined itself when that threat vanished.  See also https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11773/130.