# Why did (most of) the European NATO members support Ukraine's aspirations to joining NATO?

Tags: international-relations, ukraine, europe, nato

[This article](https://theconversation.com/ukraine-war-follows-decades-of-warnings-that-nato-expansion-into-eastern-europe-could-provoke-russia-177999) argues an alternative (maybe even complementary) view regarding the cause of the Russian invasion of Ukraine:

> (..) Russia’s security concerns are in fact genuine, and NATO
> expansion eastward is seen by Russians as directed against their
> country. Putin has been clear for many years that if continued, the
> expansion would likely be met with serious resistance by the Russians,
> even with military action.

In this regard, when [NATO leaders reiterated the decision taken at the 2008 Bucharest summit that Ukraine would become a member of the Alliance with the MAP as an integral part of the process and Ukraine's right to determine its future and foreign policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine%E2%80%93NATO_relations), the likelihood of Russia issuing a military response increased.

According to [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/70941/11278), besides quite a few disadvantages (inflation, nuclear war risk, etc.), the US might eventually benefit from the war, despite the short-term issues and risks. However, I cannot see why the European NATO members risked a military escalation in Ukraine.

Turkey blocking (or delaying) Finland and Sweden’s accession to NATO is an example of how easy one NATO member can place a roadblock on one another's country joining NATO. I guess that it would have taken only two or three important members (e.g. Germany and France) to oppose supporting Ukraine's ascension to NATO in order for June 2021 Brussels summit declaration to sound very differently.

My question is basically **what's in it for the European NATO members to support Ukraine's accession to NATO?** In the short term, there seem to be important negative consequences.

To make my question more specific, I am asking why did European NATO members agree with Ukraine's accession to NATO, as per point 69 in the [Brussels Summit Communiqué](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/news_185000.htm)?

> We reiterate the decision made at the 2008 Bucharest Summit that
> Ukraine will become a member of the Alliance with the Membership
> Action Plan (MAP) as an integral part of the process;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has any Western leader articulated how NATO would benefit from admitting Ukraine?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/70056/has-any-western-leader-articulated-how-nato-would-benefit-from-admitting-ukraine)

Comment: @DaveGremlin Not really. It is clearly related, but it does not answer my question because all answers refer to events (way) before June 2021 and I am interested in motivation at the individual country level, rather than the NATO level. Example: why did Germany accept such a risk and pay the economic price of sacrificing such a good deal for Russian gas and oil? My assumption is that any NATO-level declaration requires some kind of consensus among the countries' representatives who I assume also have their own interests.

Comment: This Q is somewhat confusing. A number of NATO countries (and depending which time we're talking about, this included Germany & France, not just Hungary) clearly were not supportive of Ukraine gaining membership anytime "soon". Which as we know can mean decades at least. So are you asking why they didn't go as far as Russia wanted and say "never"? Or are you asking about those countries (like the US or Poland, IIRC) which sometimes did [verbally] support quicker membership... even though they probably knew of the opposition from the others? (Recall that joining NATO requires unanimity.)

Comment: And regarding the June 2021 decl, which part are you talking about? I don't see that promising membership to Ukraine.

Comment: @Fizz I have added more information to the question. I have picked point 69 because it is indicated in the Wikipedia article (and also seen it mentioned in other articles as a "red line" from Moscow's perspective).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But you can see from the para you've quoted that Ukraine's application was essentially frozen since 2008, when Russia/Putin made a big deal out of it... and since the war in Georgia (which still has a nearly identical para in 2021) made it clear that he meant it. NATO not "taking back their words" while also not admitting Ukraine is face-saving, basically.

Comment: Mearsheimer had a [similar article in the Economist](https://www.economist.com/by-invitation/2022/03/11/john-mearsheimer-on-why-the-west-is-principally-responsible-for-the-ukrainian-crisis).  However, not really sure about the premise of the question's title: *the European NATO members*.  **The** European members implies they all agreed.  In fact, at no point was everyone agreed and since joining NATO requires unanimity...  Is this question about one or more *specific* members' reasons for saying yes?  Because an answer about Poland is unlikely to match say UK's.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I have also found this article but I preferred to reference a more balanced article (i.e. shows both main perspectives on why Russia invaded Ukraine). Ref. to "The European members implies they all agreed": I understand "many enough" / most if not all of the ones that have the bigger say in NATO summits/decisions. I am not familiar with how NATO leaders and their staff compile a summit declaration, but I guess they virtually all have to agree with what it says.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't "Why not go for a milder option such as de facto economically and military supporting Ukraine without joining NATO?" exactly what is done currently? Ukraine is not a member of NATO but still the country is supported by almost everyone. What point is this question trying to make? That 2008 wasn't very smart?

Comment: @Trilarion I have removed that fragment since now that you are asking, it is not very clear to me either.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrMiSQAGOS4 Mersheimer who predicted the Ukraine war, had his own theory. It's based on geopolitics and he's neutral.

Comment: Why would it be Putin's business to have any input in membership of an association?? Does he get a say who can join your tennis club too, just because he claims it affects him?

Comment: this question suggests an answer to its own premise in almost the first opening line.  why is an answer to a question shoehorned into the question itself.

Comment: @user2754 It's the motivation of the question. The user asks him/herself why it wouldn't be liked this. You could leave it out and reduce the question to the bare facts but that immediately raises the question why somebody would ask such a question or you could leave it in but mark it more clearly as context. For answering you can ignore it (or use it and simply repost it). In short: it's only context.

Comment: @aganju if he has nuclear weapons then he does. Even if you do too, because you don't want to use them. Unlike your tennis club, there's no police to complain to if you don't like it. Might is right in international politics.

Comment: The premise of this question is riddle with inaccuracies. NATO denied membership in 2008, there was no MAP plan for Ukraine or Georgia, and the most powerful members of NATO specifically said there would NOT be membership in the future. Articles that back Russia's claims that their invasion was in response to NATO expansion into Ukraine are propaganda. There was no path forward UNTIL Russia invaded.

-1 for a question based on a false premise

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look at this decade-old [Carnegie study](https://carnegieeurope.eu/2013/04/16/why-does-ukraine-matter-to-eu-pub-51522).

- **Some** European NATO members believed that a fight with a resurgent Russia was about to come, anyway, and wanted Ukraine to fight on the NATO side instead of providing recruits and war materials to Russia. Or, if they did not think that the war would certainly come, they saw it as a [distinct possibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Warsaw_summit).
  Keep in mind that Russia used to have an empire, both under the Czars and then under the Soviets. This empire has been much diminished with the fall of the Soviet Union. To many Russians, restoring the empire is [righting a historical wrong](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/putin-rues-soviet-collapse-demise-historical-russia-2021-12-12/). Many of the ex-Soviet, ex-Czarist nations are now part of NATO and the EU.
- **Some** European NATO members believed as a matter of principle that any country between Russia and NATO should be [free to make a NATO membership application](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natolive/topics_49212.htm) without a Russian veto. The application would then be for NATO to approve or reject. It does not necessarily follow that the application would have been granted, just that the Russian notion of a privileged position in the "near abroad" was rejected.
- **Many** European NATO members are also EU members, and saw a deep economic relationship between Ukraine and the EU as an advantage for the EU. (And also as a long-term advantage for Ukraine, but that might not get them involved quite as much.) Membership in the EU and NATO is not necessarily linked, but there is a significant overlap.

Comment: Actually, **most** European NATO members are also EU members. (Otherwise, it's a good answer.)

Comment: @toolforger, I was giving greater weight to the Brits than to the Portugese, even if each are one nation. Of course one could also counter with France vs. Macedonia ...

Comment: Even if you go by population size, it's still most European NATO members are in the EU, Brexit notwithstanding: 600 million in the NATO, 400 million in the EU (admittedly it's getting closer, and I'm ignoring EU members not in the NATO but I'm unaware of any significant countries in that bucket). (EDIT: Turkey IS significant I see.)

Comment: Let's say: "**Many** European NATO members are also EU members." (Given France is back in the NATO and France+Germany are the most significant  countries both in NATO and EU, I''d still feel fine if one said "most", but I won't insist.)

Comment: @toolforger, I'll edit, but note that France never left. They just pulled their forces out of the NATO command for a time -- which many US forces never entered.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that France actually never left.

Comment: @toolforger, France had a strategy of reserving the option to leave. So they built a Force de Frappe they could maintain on their own, while the Brits merely purchased US delivery systems they could launch on their own.

Answer (score 41):

I would first contest the premise made by the paragraph you cited.

> (..) **Russia’s** security concerns are in fact genuine, and NATO
> expansion eastward is seen by **Russians** as directed against their
> country. **Putin** has been clear for many years that if continued, the
> expansion would likely be met with serious resistance by the **Russians**,
> even with military action.

The author here uses "Putin" and "Russians" interchangeably, implying that Putin speaks for Russians and derives the legitimacy of his power from the mandate of the Russian people. This is a common fallacy made by people who live in democratic countries. Russia is an authoritarian state where only one person holds decision making power, that being Putin, the will of the entire Russian population is irrelevant here.

When we're talking about the response of NATO vs Russia. We're in fact talking about NATO vs Putin. NATO is a collective of democratic nation whose leaders are accountable to their voters, whereas Putin is completely unaccountable to anyone and his decisions are solely his own.

This creates a dynamic where both sides operate on entirely different sets of psychology.

- To NATO members, the ascension of Ukraine is a positive development not necessarily in terms of military or economic gain (though that is part of it), but primarily in terms of value. It is a sign that Ukraine is coming to its own as a democracy, making its own decisions, and most importantly it is choosing to look West rather than East. It signifies an expansion of democratic Europe and a loss of influence of authoritarian Russia.
- To Putin, however, the loss of Ukraine signifies something entirely different. As Ukraine looks West rather than East, he sees a set of geopolitical plots orchestrated by United States to oppress Russia. And Ukraine - in Putin's mind an integral part of the Russian empire - is something that has to be reeled back into where it belongs. It should not be understated that **Putin is profoundly paranoid** (colloquially called "[dictator syndrome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irzB-C9eSrQ)") and he has been living in his own make-believe reality for a long time. And as he becomes more paranoid, his decisions become more erratic and unpredictable.

It's very important to recognize that **both sides are not living in the same reality. And they both underestimate how wide the gap is between their realities.**

To answer your question: Why do European NATO members support Ukraine ascension to NATO:

1. The first reason is that they believe it is a relatively low-stakes decision. Ukraine joining NATO was meant to be a symbolic positive gain for democratic value rather than an actual preparation for Russian attack. They **thought** that Putin was more or less on the same page, but they were wrong.
2. The second reason is they underestimated Putin's paranoia. They did not expect that Putin would do such a thing because Putin himself had kept his thinking elusive. It would be inconceivable to convince NATO members that Putin believed what he revealed to believe since the invasion began. **They simply did not know how to think like a dictator.**

Comment: This is an interesting perspective and it makes sense. Ref. to "They simply did not know how to think like a dictator" Aren't political leaders supposed to be helped by advisors to understand the way a very different leader sees the world? Also, the Conversation source I have referenced mentions that US officials understood back in 2008 that "Ukrainian entry into NATO is the brightest of all redlines for the Russian elite (not just Putin)".

Comment: @Alexei Yes, it's true that European countries have arguably the best diplomatic apparatus on the planet, but they do have blindspots. For one, it's easier to guess how other democratic leaders think because they make their thoughts transparent, even Viktor Orban of Hungary has to make his far-right beliefs public to keep his base happy. Putin, however, does not need to make his intentions transparent. It's not a surprise that even Russians themselves were shocked when the invasion began. Putin lives in his own world and we don't know how he would act until he does.

Comment: @Alexei Regarding the additional edit. Again I will have to reiterate that I do not think Russian elites have a say in the matter. Putin had created such a tight control of the Russian state that he could effectively overrule them, and that's kind of what he did. I suspect US and other European countries simply underestimated Putin's psychology. It's not clear what they meant by "red line" either, does it mean economic sanction? Nuclear war? No one could've known.

Comment: I guess "red line" meant something that might lead to military intervention. IIRC there were some interviews with Putin (or some other high official) mentioning it more explicitly. [Possible example](https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20211221-putin-warns-west-of-military-measures-over-ukraine-threats)

Comment: @Alexei There's an interesting argument - and it's the one I lean towards - which posits that Putin's response has more to do with Russia's own internal structure than anything that the West did. It's not a coincidence that Russia has always been autocratic, isolationist, and flirted with imperialism. The vastness of its territory combined with weak internal cohesion calls for authoritarian rule to keep the state together. It's perhaps not a surprise that - historically - Russian leaders had always viewed the West as a threat because it undermines what is necessary to hold Russia together.

Comment: @Alexei Some readings for the theory I mentioned above. 1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Mm3hgc1hhg 2) https://foreignpolicy.com/2022/03/12/putins-thousand-year-war/

Comment: People in Russia have seen NATO as the main threat to their country long befor putin, this was one of the reasons he became president 2000.

Comment: This answer contains a great deal of speculation, without a single reference to a comment or decision made by any NATO member state. I don't see how this can possibly constitute a good answer to the actual question, in its current form.

Comment: A native here. You're dead right on saying that there's a wide gap in perception of reality between Russia and NATO... Inability to understand each other realities (and account for them) could even be the cause of those violent outcome that we're seeing now... But I'm writing this comment to share my observation (anecdotal, I admit, based on my social circle; and no, I do not qualify as "elite", not even close) that many Russians do support Putin's goal to keep NATO further away, even though the military action wasn't expected. So the fallacy mentioned in the answer isn't that undisputable.

Comment: And this is why China is about the scariest thing ever to face against the US. Its ability to affect entire MARKETS is something that the US is not prepared to deal with. Just look at the amount of companies trying to enter the Chinese market, then subsequently get a shit-ton of tech stolen and then ejected from China with absolutely no recourse. People are starting to genuinely realize that China is not a free-market at all. It is kind of free-ish, but it can vanish at the snap of a finger (a la private education sector... it literally evaporated overnight).

Comment: *NATO is a collective of democratic nation* — that's not true.  Turkey is n NATO, and [Greece was in NATO when ruled by a military junta](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11773/130).  Nato was founded as a collective of anti-Soviet Union nations, to assist in mutual defence against a perceived threat from the Soviet Union and its satellite states.

Comment: You say that Russia is an authoritarian state, but so is any republic. What you meant, I think, is dictatorship or tyranny.

Comment: Also, not all nations in NATO are "democratic". France, for example, is a republic, in which the citizen do not decide anything but who is going to rule them. That is not the definition of actual democraty and this is why we have "republic" just before/after the word "democraty" in countries name.

Comment: @Itération122442 That's evidently not true. Plenty of republics are not authoritarian (e.g. Iceland, Ireland, Finland, Germany, France, Estonia, etc). A repbulic basically just means "not a monarchy".

Comment: @Itération122442 Of course France is a democracy. A democracy is a system in which the authority of the government is based on the will of the people. Since the French President is accountable to the voters and the French Prime Minsiter is accountable to the demcoratcially elected parliament, France therefore qualifies as a democracy.

Comment: @QuantumWalnut Well, my definition came from Hanna Ardendt (in Crisis of Cultulre), but dictionnaries give you reason.

Comment: Good answer, though I would substitute the "Russian Nationalist Movement" for Putin, who is only the most prominent, and by no means the most radical in that group. I would say Russia has been captured by them, and if Putin is removed, he is just as likely to be replaced by someone more radical than by someone less radical (at this point).

Comment: Not a bad answer, but ultimately based on an *ad hominem* argument that Russia is run by Putin's wims alone, and that his behavior is irrational. This is not provable, and also likely false, as we can see both from the past experiences, as well as from the testimonies of those who had to deal with Putin personally (e.g., Condolezza Rice, Robert Gates and John Bolton all characterize Putin as an ultimately rational in his dealings, even if not a "nice guy"). The invasion of Ukraine was also hardly unpredictable - given that the US had been predicting it for a few months beforehand.

Comment: This answer implies that Russia as a country is solely determined by Putin, which is untrue. It implies that there is no internationally-observed democracy present in Russia, which there is. It paints NATO as an organisation that only seeks to selflessly spread democracy, and not to just enjoy Ukraine as a proxy-war actor. It doesn't mention Russia's decade-long wait for Ukraine to commit to the neutrality like it already agreed to. It's a narrative, but it hardly seems a neutral presentation of reality.

Comment: @user2979044 The Economist's Democracy Index puts Russia as solidly authoritarian. Given that Putin's been President or Prime Minister of Russia for over twenty years, and when he was Prime Minister, his puppet/ally was President, that seems quite reasonable.

Answer (score 15):

NATO is a [defensive](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/126169.htm) organization based on belief that security cannot be achieved by "not provoking Russia". They assume, if Russia thinks they can rather easily win over NATO or whatever, they will attack regardless how polite you are and what discounts do you offer them. If they see a danger to lose, they will not, regardless if you send them where that ship has gone or you not. This is the philosophy.

It is the military power where the safety is. More fight-capable members means more military power and hence more safety. Hence it is useful to include as fight-capable member as the Ukraine is.

You can read [here](https://www.csis.org/analysis/resetting-natos-defense-and-deterrence-sword-and-shield-redux) about the official NATO philosophy: *if you want peace, prepare for war*. The nuclear war is not everything they think about, they also think about the *graduated response to a non-nuclear crisis*.

Comment: Are there any sources corroborating the claims in this answer. Did anyone from NATO say something along these lines?

Comment: While not cited in the answer, I'd argue yes: https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/topics_133127.htm NATO bases their existence on deterring an attack, both via nuclear means and conventional strength, through article 5.

Comment: Reference added

Comment: The reference is one commentator's opinion of what he thinks NATO is about. It mostly quotes from NATO documents written before 1968, when the USSR wasn't terribly capable of wiping out life on the entire planet with their nukes. One could easily argue that the various efforts of NATO to engage with Russia, especially after the fall of the USSR point to a far more nuanced approach. OTOH, the view from Poland may indeed be more like what the position paper says, so ironically while this is a misleading answer to the position of NATO visavis Russia 1990-2014, it's less wrong with regard to EE.

Comment: The reference is a review that covers NATO concepts up to 2010.

Answer (score 13):

The questions isn't asking what that the US saw or sees in Ukraine's membership,
although that is an interesting trip down the memory lane, if one looks back at
Bush's statements around that 2008 summit. (Hint: at least in speeches, it had a lot to do
with the relatively simple divisions between good and evil that that US administration saw,
and how they justified some of their other foreign policy in the name of supporting
freedom and emerging democracy, in Islamic countries and elsewhere.)

But if we take the US decision as a given (since the Q isn't interesting in exploring that),
the Eastern European countries that had been recently admitted had good reasons to
be on the side of the US on this: besides whatever genuine gratitude they may have had
for being admitted in essence largely due to the same policies, there's obvious
"strength in numbers" as well not wanting to be necessarily on the "front line" if
the cold war divisions became more relevant again. Germany probably saw an advantage in that when
Poland was admitted in NATO. Poland in turn sees a similar advantage in having Ukraine
admitted.

There's also the fact that a number of Eastern European countries already had worse
relations with Russia than Germany & France, ranging from conflicts over the Russian
minority in the Baltics, to the more symbolic spats over Soviet-era monuments in several
other countries from the former Eastern Bloc.

While one is free to speculate whether a "finlandization" of Ukraine was possible,
as some paragon of "real" neutrality, Putin never stopped trying to influence countries
to its West (and in the former Soviet Union, more broadly). Absent NATO engagement, Ukraine might have become another Belarus instead:
a much less democratic country that's essentially a free maneuver ground for Russian troops,
occasional enabler of emigrant surges from the Middle-East, and hijacker of aircraft under fake bomb warning claims. Why would Poland want to risk/prefer
Ukraine to be like that as well?

Now, fast forward to 2021, and why NATO "stays the course", i.e. why they didn't publicly
admit that the membership prospects of Ukraine (and Georgia) were in fact much more unlikely than
in early 2008... it surely has a lot to do with saving face on the open-door policy.
After all, North Macedonia (if I'm using the right name) and Montenegro had been admitted as NATO members
in the meantime, despite the Russian (non-military) opposition to them as well.
Neither North Macedonia nor Montenegro had been on the clear list in 2008, so in a sense they "jumped the queue" ahead of Ukraine and Georgia... although North Macedonia was omitted in 2008 due
to an outright veto of Greece back then (over naming dispute), rather than other reasons.

France and Germany, on
the other hand, probably saw more of an advantage in a "soft veto" over Ukraine & Georgia, where they
simultaneously agreed to the admission-in-principle to placate the US and the Eastern
European members, while putting out [clear](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-nato-france-ukraine-idUSL0115117020080401) statements that they didn't see Ukraine's membership
happening anytime soon, to placate Russia. (France and Germany were also the main European supporters of the Minsk agreements.) Probably not much had changed in that compromise by 2021.
If one looks at the NATO summits after 2014, there were various "Comprehensive Action Plans" for Ukraine, but which US commentators [complained](https://jamestown.org/program/nato-shows-an-irresolute-flag-in-ukraine-part-two/) that the US was bearing the majority of the costs thereof.  (Also, the parts regarding Ukraine in NATO communiques were pretty much copy-paste, year after year, according to [part one of] that analysis.)

Comment: Yeah, before someone else comments on this, I realize that the 2022 invasion ended up sending many more (Ukrainian) refugees in Poland than Belarus could have possibly ever managed to funnel, even assuming they kept at it for decades. On the other hand, Poland was much more used to Ukrainian temp workers etc.; the acceptance of immigrants from Islamic countries being much lower in Poland... to put it diplomatically.

Answer (score 8):

> [The opposing view argues that] Russia’s security concerns are in fact genuine, and NATO expansion eastward is seen by Russians as directed against their country. Putin has been clear for many years that if continued, the expansion would likely be met with serious resistance by the Russians, even with military action.

This seems like a rather problematic premise.

In effect, it's saying that countries aren't allowed to create treaties with one another if those treaties can be seen as a threat to another country (regardless of how unreasonable this perception may be). And this justifies said country from starting a war in other countries to prevent said treaty from going into effect.

Specifically in the face of these threats, what NATO members gain by supporting Ukraine's accession to NATO is:

- supporting a country's right to determine its future and foreign policy,
- evoking the members' right to determine their own foreign policies and
- strengthening the alliance those members are already part of, and providing benefits along with that (as briefly summarised in [an answer to *Has any Western leader articulated how NATO would benefit from admitting Ukraine?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/70061/15027)),

without having this be dictated by the fears and threats of another country.

Although these threats were presumably taken into account when making the decision.

---

There may also be somewhat of an implication in the question that European NATO members are somewhat to blame for Russia invading Ukraine, which is also problematic. The only party responsible for Russia invading Ukraine is Russia.

Comment: Very strange of you to call "just a treaty between countries" an organization that have military bases worldwide and wage wars of aggression however they like for decades.

Answer (score 7):

## They lost trust in the usefulness of peaceful means

The invasion in Ukraine meant that Russia would refuse to accept any non-military bounds[1], so the only recourse available is military.

Also, there are signs that Russian leadership considers the European countries "soft" and unwilling to wage a even defensive war; *not* engaging in the Ukraine war will confirm that impression, and possibly make Russia attack NATO countries directly. [2]
A military defense in Ukraine is much cheaper than defending against Russian aggression in one's own country, anyway. NOT defending and simply submitting to Russian demands would almost as expensive, as Russian economy is considered ineffective (poor standards of living, top government not just mildly corrupt like in Western countries but outright cleptocratic).

Additonally, Ukraine is the perfect candidate for countering Russian expansion plans:

- Ukraine has demonstrated willingness and ability to withstand Russian attack (given enough military equipment, but that would be needed against any military aggression).
- NATO troops in Ukraine would scare Russia, deterring them from military aggression.
- NATO would be in control of how much pressure they exert, which is a pretty attractive thought even if you know you have to avoid triggering a Russian suicide attack.
- The cost is roughly the same, whether you deflect it in Ukraine or elsewhere. (Russia cannot attack other countries while occupied in Ukraine, they lack the military power for that.)

[1] They refused to let themselves be bound by daily communication: They claimed that the troop movements near the border were a maneuver, but that turned out to be untrue.
They refused to let themselves bound by older promises: There had been promises that Ukraine would *not* be invaded, or its borders altered by aggressive means.
They removed economic ties to the best of their abilities, by building up foreign exchange reserves.
They never accepted self-restraint as a bound; losing the Warsaw Pact states as vassals is widely considered a tragic loss, and Putin has been reinforcing that idea on several occasions.

[2] NATO countries need to declare that they want NATO help to fend off an attacker. If Russia can overwhelm a NATO country faster than it can invoke help, or threaten massive destruction so that the country will rather submit to agression rather than defend, Russian can indeed attack and subjugate a NATO country without triggering a NATO response.

Answer (score 3):

There is no immediate advantage. In fact, the disadvantages are massive.

But Ukraine is one of those countries that are on the edge between the Russian and the Western sphere of influence. In Geo-Politics, bringing Ukraine into the western sphere of influence enlarges that sphere, while reducing that of Russia. It doesn't matter that it makes no sense in other ways, especially economically.

Geo-politics are game played over decades and centuries. In that perspective, it matters little if Ukraine is a drain on the EU economy for years and years, or if a couple billions are lost to military equipment, or if a few trillions are lost in economic power due to sanctions backfiring and rising energy costs. The only currency in the game that matters is power.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, as I THINK I agree with you. My own view is that since the end of the cold-war, open-access and "defensive" NATO has been pushed far too readily by the major western powers into the former Warsaw-pact territory and beyond. There is a reason why we are having to deal with a Putin and not a Gorbachev. (In the same way there was good reason why Hindenberg became Hitler - Versailles and all that.) We are inexorably driving Russia into a corner. And that is not a good place to push the world's second-largest nuclear power.

Answer (score 2):

The interest of most European nations in Ukraine joining NATO wasn't about NATO, it was about Ukraine being a Western facing country politically and economically. Bringing the Eastern European countries, in general, into the Western European fold has provided new markets, new suppliers, a stronger workforce, and greater political clout to the collective. The same applies to Ukraine. Accepting Ukraine as a potential future NATO member was part of this general political outlook, rather the primary point.

Meanwhile few people in the collective West believed that Russia would engage in a major military conflict in Ukraine. Even in February, immediately before the invasion, many commentators argued that war was unlikely. The MacDonalds theory of conflict was widely believed, and European countries believed that building stronger and stronger economic ties would prevent any major conflict from flaring up (aside: I find it frankly bizarre that this belief continued post-2014, but that seems to have been the case).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the European NATO members support Ukraine's aspirations to joining NATO for these reasons:

- Ukraine has unparalleled recent experience in fighting overwhleming Russian forces with skill and bravery.
- Ukraine spends about 5% of its GDP on defense, more than an average NATO country.
- Ukraine provides a safer buffer against Russia.
- Ukraine has been a NATO partner for almost 30 years.
- Ukraine offers NATO access to Ukraine’s physical, technological and human capital.
- Ukraine's NATO membership and associated anti-corruption, pro-democracy and pro-free market reforms will provide an example for similar reform forces in Russia, leading to greater peace and stability in Europe long-term.

**REFERENCES:**

> - Ukraine’s military and political leadership has unparalleled recent experience in
>   resisting and combatting Russia's cross-domain assertiveness and even aggression that
>   all NATO member-states would benefit from. This applies to both the kinetic and -
>   arguably even more so - non-kinetic realms.
> - The Ukrainian military’s first-hand knowledge of Russian military thinking and action is
>   probably second to only Belarus’. Most members of Ukraine’s current top military
>   leadership were educated and trained alongside Russia’s current top military
>   leadership. This deep knowledge of the Russian military has furthermore been
>   significantly enriched - including in an intelligence sense - during four years of both ‘hot’
>   and ‘cold’ battles.
> - Ukraine currently spends about 5 percent of its GDP on defense, more than all NATO
>   members except the United States. Its membership would contribute far more to NATO
>   capabilities than Montenegro’s recent accession – a country with a small army, no public
>   consent on NATO and a strong pro-Russian lobby.
> - Kyiv would be able to provide means of transportation to quickly redeploy NATO troops
>   and equipment from Central and Western Europe to Poland or the Baltic states. Not only
>   would it improve the overall operational mobility of NATO forces, but it would also send
>   a clear message to Russia that NATO is well-prepared.
> - Ukrainian military reform, while still decidedly suboptimal, has nevertheless rendered
>   its armed forces more performant than ever before - a development that has not been
>   lost on Russian military leaders.
>   [...]
> - The West’s cautious attitude towards Ukrainian membership thus far may have only
>   emboldened Russian assertiveness. Russia has made it increasingly clear over the past
>   few years that it only respects ‘force’. Offering Ukraine a Membership Action Plan would
>   send Russia a uniquely bold and unambiguous deterrent signal.
> - Ukraine has been a trustworthy NATO partner for almost 30 years, making rather
>   humble, but still important contributions to the collective security. Since 1990's, Ukraine
>   has been providing its troops, equipment and intelligence to assist numerous NATO-led
>   peace-support operations in the Balkans, Afghanistan, Iraq, and the Mediterranean Sea.
>   Ukraine has also been participating in numerous joint programs with NATO
>   [...]
> - Better security would have a stabilizing effect on Ukraine’s economy, which would
>   enable it to become a better economic partner for NATO countries.
> - NATO membership would give NATO unfettered access to Ukraine’s physical,
>   technological and human capital at uniquely attractive price points. This applies to
>   Ukraine’s military-industrial economic potential, but arguably even more so to its
>   outsized broader agricultural and IT resources.
>   [...]
> - Europe (including Ukraine) will never be fully safe and secure without a transformed
>   Russia. Under current circumstances, such a transformation in Russia is highly
>   improbable - first and foremost in identity and cultural terms - in the short- to mediumterm. Many Russians expect Ukrainian reforms to fail, thereby ‘proving’ that there is no
>   ‘other way’ for them. (Re-)Integrating Ukraine into the European and transatlantic
>   family of nations is therefore an indispensable first step towards not only Ukraine’s, but
>   also Russia’s return.
> - Ukraine embodies a unique combination of 'Western' and 'Eastern' values that is
>   different, but not entirely dissimilar to Russia’s. Acceptance in NATO would demonstrate
>   that convergence of these value systems is feasible.

*Why NATO May Want Ukraine: The Western Case in Favor of Ukrainian NATO Membership. Stephan De Spiegeleire, Khrystyna Holynska, Yevhen Sapolovych. The Hague Centre for Strategic Studies. April 10, 2018: https://kse.ua/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Khrystyna_180410_Why_NATO_Might_Want_Ukraine_-_Final_HCSS_version_Print-1.pdf*

Answer (score -2):

You ask: *...what's in it for the European NATO members to support Ukraine's accession to NATO?*

The answer is that it satisfies the cold-war mindset with which the  major NATO powers are still imbued.

The Gorbachev era gave us an opportunity to move beyond that - it was an olive branch. And there is a reason why we now find ourselves having to deal with a Putin rather than a Gorbachev. (Similarly there were reasons why Hindenberg gave way to Hitler - and the reasons were not all German induced.)

As Shakespeare pointed out "There is a tide in the affairs of men, which taken at the flood leads on to fortune. Omitted, all the voyage of their lives is bound in shallows and in misery." - or words to that effect in *Julius Caesar*.

That tide came in the 1980s to the Reagan and Thatcher administrations. They didn't have to do anything to get it - it simply presented itself. The Russians even allowed the pulling down of the Wall - the very icon of Soviet defence. The USSR was virtually bankrupt - economically and politically.

Benefitting from hindsight it is clear now that we should have better managed the transition of European defence architecture. Installing "defensive" NATO up to the borders of Russia - installed in the very lands across which the Polish Commonwealth, Napoleonic France and the German Third Reich had savaged their way, and caused untold bloodshed before discovering that their supply lines were too long to sustain the momentum - was not a smart idea.

**Pushing the world's second most powerful nuclear power into a corner might sound an attractive proposition - but only to people suffering severe myopia.**

**Churchill in his history *The Second World War* states as the "Moral of the Work" four aphorisms : *In War - Resolution; In Defeat - Defiance; In Victory: Magnanimity; In Peace - Goodwill*. It was the third of those that escaped our consideration.**

Comment: I note the drive-by shooter has done his or her worst. Would the discourteous lady or gentleman care to explain themselves?

Comment: Regardless of our opinion on NATO I don't think 'occupying' is the best choice of words given that >70% of Poles, Lithuanians, Hungarians, Estonians, Latvians etc. wants to stay in NATO. Also NATO border is nowhere close to extent of Polish Commonwealth during Dimitriads. The border was behind Smolensk making it about 350 km to Moscow. Ukraine is slightly less than 500 km from Moscow. Now you might argue successfully that it imbue on Russian psyche. You may argue that it wasn't smart from western perspective to extend NATO. But I think you try to erase that NATO was and is wanted by people...

Comment: ... in those countries. And rightly or wrongly those countries feared Russian expansionism. Based on history. In Ukraine you had Holdomor; In Poland, Stalin is not remembered the best to say at least and tsardom partition is still remembered; etc. You can argue if those feeling are justified and if the expantion of NATO was justified but bottom line was that "occupation" is very much misrepresentation of situation on the ground. In many cases the countries are less occupied than western Europe based on support.

Comment: "The Gorbachev era gave us an opportunity to move beyond that - it was an olive branch." Are you talking about him [sending tanks to Lithuania?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_Events_(Lithuania))

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka I would agree that "occupying" was not a good word to have chosen - and I wasn't using it in the sense of an army of occupation - that is something quite different. However to avoid any misunderstanding I have now eliminated that word.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec How do you account for the rise of Putinesque government in Russia?

Comment: The (likely) reason you're attracting all these downvotes is that you've barely attempted to answer the question beyond "it satisfies the cold-war mindset with which the major NATO powers are still imbued". The entire rest of your answer is just your personal opinion on what *should* have happened, which has nothing at all to do with the question. To improve the answer you should delete all paragraphs except the first 2, and then expand upon the 2nd to justify it.

Comment: @JBentley The way is open to you to supply your own answer - should you feel so inclined.

Comment: @WS2 Do you really expect I'll write a historical essay in comments section? You can read [this analysis](https://twitter.com/kamilkazani/status/1496711906412933121)

Comment: OK, maybe rather [this one](https://twitter.com/kamilkazani/status/1496506490202513413)

Comment: @TadeuszKopec My suggestion was not to you but to the person to whom it was addressed.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why I'd write my own answer merely because I've pointed out the problem with yours. I quote: "Would the discourteous lady or gentleman care to explain themselves". If you don't want to know, don't ask. The fact remains that this is not an answer to the question which the OP asked.

Comment: @JBentley I answered it with my second sentence.