# Why do Poland and Lithuania push for NATO membership for Ukraine instead of sending troops to Ukraine directly?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, nato, poland, lithuania

[Lithuanian and Polish presidents visit Kyiv, back Ukraine's path to NATO](https://www.msn.com/en-gb/news/world/lithuanian-and-polish-presidents-visit-kyiv-back-ukraines-path-to-nato/ar-AA1da5py)

Lithuania and Poland are in favor of Ukraine joining NATO. Presumably, this is because they view it as NATO's duty to protect Ukraine from future Russian aggression. But if they're interested in defending Ukraine from future Russian aggression, why don't they just send troops into Ukraine now? They still get to defend Ukraine, and they get to do it immediately too.

The first explanation that comes to mind is that they are concerned they lack the military power for such an intervention, but then they presumably should argue for a NATO combat deployment to Ukraine, and I haven't seen them do that. Another possibility is that they are worried they'll be attacked if they intervene, but if Ukraine joins NATO then their chances of a future war with Russia goes up, so they should be psychologically ready for a war with Russia already. More pragmatically, both countries are already protected by NATO, and moreover, it doesn't look like Russia is capable of attacking, since Russia is heavily engaged in Ukraine + are not winning that war.

The only other explanation I can see is not very flattering: they want NATO (i.e., the US) to help Ukraine directly but don't want to do it themselves.

Comment: The OP seems either confused or pursuing some kind of political point. Nato membership for Ukraine wouldn't mean that Poland and Lithuania will have to fight on their own against Russia in the event of an attack on Ukraine: it means precisely the opposite, that Polish armed forces will operate as a part of Nato armed forces fighting together, which would have a chance of defeating Russia.

Comment: "if Ukraine joins NATO then their chances of a future war with Russia goes up" This is entirely speculative. Nobody knows that. Maybe had Ukraine joined NATO in 2009, nothing would have happened there at all. I personally think that Russia is in no shape for any future war.

Comment: It's not only Poland and Lithuania that advocated for NATO membership of Ukraine. There are at least [7 more](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/10/02/world/europe/nine-european-nations-express-support-for-ukraines-bid-for-nato-membership.html).

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution, in fact, Spain becomes **21st** country that supported Ukraine's NATO membership — [Zelenskyy](https://www.pravda.com.ua/eng/news/2023/07/1/7409427/); **All** NATO members have agreed Ukraine will eventually join — [Stoltenberg](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/apr/21/all-nato-members-have-agreed-ukraine-will-eventually-join-says-stoltenberg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I have to point out some incorrect assumptions.

> Presumably this is because they view it as NATO's duty to protect Ukraine from future Russian aggression.

NATO's duty is to protect its members, period. One could argue that protecting Ukraine from Russia will improve security of NATO's members (among them Poland and Lithuania), but by no means it is a duty of NATO.

However, as each country will work towards what's in their best interests, for Poland and Lithuania as long as Ukraine remains a buffer state between them and Russia, they will be much safer. And, as both of these countries have in recent history been just liberated from Russian control, the general public will be much more sympathetic to Ukrainians in this situation. And if the general public wants to help Ukraine, politicians have it in their best interest to do just that.

> they are concerned they lack the military power for such an intervention

Such a concern makes no sense. They wouldn't be going to fight Russia alone, they would be helping Ukrainian forces that already seem to be holding their own pretty well. The concern for military power being insufficient would have any merit if troops were being sent into a losing battle, and the question would be are they enough to turn the tide. With a draw or winning fight they don't have to turn the tide.

> if Ukraine joins NATO then their chances of a future war with Russia goes up

That would be objectively true if Russians were crazy berserkers that go into fights without concern for winning or for losses they might take. NATO does not have to fight to be useful, deterrence is enough. Russia went into this war thinking of Ukraine as an easy target. They know that fighting Ukraine + entire NATO will be much, much harder, so they might give up on a future invasion due to it being simply not feasible.

> it doesn't look like Russia is capable of attacking

It doesn't look like Russia is able of **conquering** Lithuania and Poland right now, attacking is whole other story. In Ukraine, Russian military has a habit of launching rockets on civilian targets. Poland and Lithuania don't want that happening on their soil, obviously. There can also be other assets (navy, etc.) that right now are "protected" by threat of NATO retaliation. But will this stil be the case if Poland and Lithuania attack Russian army without being attacked first? As often with international politics, it's not as certain, as Article 5 is triggered when member is attacked, not when it's attacking.

> they want NATO (i.e., the US) to help Ukraine directly, but don't want to do it themselves

This is straight up nonsense. Poland and Lithuania are both helping Ukraine a lot, since the start of the war. They are trying (pretty succesfully so far) to convince their allies to do the same. Neither Poland or Ukraine argue for others to help in ways they're not already helping themselves (if they're capable). In case of Ukraine joining NATO after the war, Poland and Lithuania will be just as obliged to help in potential next war as the other NATO members.

### Public support

Democratic nations are ruled by people that more heavily rely on public support for their decisions and might quickly lose power if they act against public opinion. If the public doesn't want to send soldiers, you have to either give in to their demands, convince them or risk being removed from your office.

### War declarations are not made easily

Having your army fight the other country's army means you are at war with them (except in cases when both sides decide to cover it up to avoid escalation, as was the case with USSR pilots in Korean war). When you are at war, the enemy will start targetting you, and as Russia proved in Ukraine already, they have no problem attacking civilian targets just to terrorize the population.

### Sending your troops costs lives and money and is never an easy choice. Sending equipment on the other hand costs only money.

Once your soldiers are fighting in frontline combat, there will almost certainly be casualties. Citizens don't like it when their people are being killed and the public support for participating in the war can drop quickly.

Moreover, mobilizing your troops, organizing everything for their deployment, preparing logistics from scratch can cost you a lot of money. What if you used that money to buy some tanks/drones/artillery and just give it to Ukrainians to bolster their forces, especially since it might make a bigger difference than more foot soldiers on the front line.

### Single, coherent force is better than multiple disorganized groups

NATO spends a lot of time and money on making a mix of armies be able to work together. Establishing protocols, command structures etc. beforehand means that NATO troops will know how to work with each other. With Ukrainians, not as much. And there are multiple potential problems with having your soldiers fight alongside allies, some smaller, some bigger:

1. For Ukrainians, they have armed people in their country they don't have full control over. What if a NATO soldier by mistake does something bad, but you can't hold him responsible for it, because he's not "yours"?
2. Making plans. For combined armies of Ukraine and NATO to cooperate on anything strategically important, they would have to make their plans together (what if they don't agree on something?), or at least share their plans (quite secret) with each other. If you make plans and tell your allies they can join in afterwards, your plans have take into account that they might not be willing to accept them, so you need to make those plans in a way that can work without them. But if they do accept, then you're likely not using your combined potential to its fullest.
3. Communication. Can be much worse in this case due to language barriers. If Lithuanian squad unexpectedly spots a soldier during the night when they can't see which side he's on, what if they can't recognize can't communicate and able to identify each other? Unnecessary friendly fire? Also apart from language barrier, the information flow might cause problems - what if one group calls artillery fire on enemy position, but the other group is about to assault it and get hit by that friendly artillery?
4. Blaming. There will be losses, but in some cases one side might feel like they got the short end of the stick in this cooperation deal, as the other is not really pulling its weight. If NATO troops retreat due to losses, which leaves a Ukrainian unit exposed/encircled (also due to communication problems), this can sour relations. In case of a single army, the command is supposed to hold it together

### Escalation always carries risk

If you're escalating the conflict, the other side is sure to respond in kind, as long as they can. Russia threatened military response if NATO will send equipment to Ukraine, but as we know now those were empty threats, since they couldn't afford such an unnecessary escalation, especially with their forces already committed in Ukraine.

TL;DR: Sending equipment is easy and doesn't really cause any further problems for Poland and Lithuania, as Russia doesn't respond to that with anything but empty threats. Sending troops is very problematic, not as efficient as you might think, and can have some unforeseen consequences.

Answer (score 11):

> why don't they just send troops into Ukraine now?

#### a) Lithuania and Poland go into Ukraine now, guns blazing.

These 2 are NATO nations.  Article 5 does not apply, as Poland and Lithuania are not being attacked, but... we could very well get WW3 from it, because Russia might very well see it as NATO forces firing on Russian forces.

Not a good idea, at all, on par with the no-fly zones.
Yes, Russia could just leave, but do you want to bet on it?

#### Ukraine joins NATO, *after the "special military operation" has stopped.*

(let's leave aside the question of whether NATO accession can happen if Ukraine still has a pending territorial dispute).

Also, let's *assume* this is what Poland and Lithuania have in mind, because you can be sure that at least one member - unanimity required - will cast a big fat **no!** if it came up for accession while the war was hot.

Russia at that point could:

###### b) Leave Ukraine alone.

From NATO's PoV, this is the sweet spot, Russia lets it happen and then settles down after that point and behaves.  This is common defense dissuasion at its best.  It's highly likely to be stable, once it has stabilized, but not certain either.  That's what Poland and Lithuania are shooting for.

###### c) Russia goes ballistic before/as Ukraine joins NATO.  Or, freaks out for some reason later.

This is more Russia being paranoid than scenario d) below.  An overreaction and one of the reason I am not sold on the idea of Ukraine accession even after the war ends.

Somewhat unlikely, but WW3 is possible in that case.

Not a fan of the USSR, but [Able Archer in 1983](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/the-1983-military-drill-that-nearly-sparked-nuclear-war-with-the-soviets-180979980/) seems to have been just a case of Soviet paranoia, rather than Putin's 2022 malevolence.

###### d) Russia decides to reinvade anyway, after Ukraine has joined.

This is Russia being willfully nasty, a la Feb 24, 2022.

Highly unlikely, but WW3 is probable in that case.  Just like WW3 is probable if Russia invades Lithuania now.  If Ukraine is part of NATO, so be it, that's what NATO is signing up for.

Still, cases c and d are both based on Russia doing something stupid.

While a) is very much a case of 2 NATO nations doing something stupid.  That NATO itself would be very unwise to support:  we have 5k nukes on the planet ready to go if "misunderstandings" happen.

**The risks of something going very wrong, if 2 NATO members's forces enter a hot war zone in Ukraine now are just considerably higher than the risks of managing Ukraine's entry into NATO once a ceasefire has been reached.  Or a latter re-invasion from Russia.**

p.s. both Poland and Lithuania give plenty of support to Ukraine so accusing them of shirking is somewhat BS.

Comment: I +1'ed this answer, but I feel like it doesn't answer the question. Poland and Lithuania sending troops into Ukraine is obviously escalating the war, but so is inducting Ukraine into NATO. If the two countries are OK with the latter (and thereby escalating future wars with Russia), then presumably they are also OK with escalating the current war with Russia, and this answer doesn't address that beyond calling it "something stupid".

Comment: @Allure "escalating future wars with Russia". The point is to avoid future wars with Russia. Do you mean future Russian aggressions are inevitable?

Comment: @TadeuszKopec no, but they presumably consider the probability of a future war with Russia as >0, or there'd be no point of inducting Ukraine into NATO.

Comment: @Allure And they consider that inducting Ukraine into NATO strongly decreases this probability. The point is to avoid war, not to win it.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec are you saying that my comment to the question, "I suppose another possibility is that Lithuania and Poland are bluffing about defending Ukraine in a future hypothetical war - but that's also not very flattering", is essentially correct? Because that's what it seems like to me if your comment is true - they only want to deter, and will balk at actually fighting if the deterrence fails.

Comment: @Allure I grew up near the end of the actual Cold War.  The overriding principle - that served the world very well - was not to have NATO - Warsaw troops shooting at each other.  Proxy - NATO?  OK.  Proxy - Warsaw?  OK.  Once integrated into NATO, UA would, hopefully, be off-limits to RU so there would be no war.  That is not a certainty, RU may pursue its war needlessly to avoid accession and RU may, unintentionally, overreact as well.  But NATO accession  is not the same thing as directly pitting NATO - RU troops against each other.  If not "stupid", think "irresponsible" / "reckless".

Comment: And, no, I assume that if UA joins NATO, then yes, NATO *will* defend Ukraine's territory against external aggressions.  Rather than bluffing.  That's not something I have a problem with and I certainly don't think Lithuania or Poland are playing that game.  What I do have concerns with is RU miscalculating about the threats of an in-NATO Ukraine.  On the other side, continued support for UA accession is a bargaining chip at this point that would be foolish to give up wo Russian concessions.  Even if the end might instead be UA EU membership and reliance on EU 42.7 article rather than NATO 5.

Comment: @Allure A remark regarding point a): wars, when seen from the US or Western Europe look like something abstract, almost a chess game, since most of wars that these countries have been involved in since WW2 were fought far away and involved very little part of their population (mostly professional soldiers). This is not what war with Russia would look like for Poland and Lithuania - they will have to draft their population to fight, and they will get bombed. Lithuania can be overrun in a few hours, while Poland, at best, would go through the same hell that Ukraine goes through now.

Comment: Remember that while NATO members are obligated to consider an aggression on another NATO member as an aggression on themselves, they're not obligated to respond in any way, militaristic or not. If Ukraine joins and then it's attacked, NATO could very well decide it's better for the rest of them not to actively intervene in Ukraine. Not an ideal scenario for NATO (especially for other NATO members that might be at some risk), but it is an option for NATO if they wish to take that route.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical answer to this question is that…

### Because Ukraine has never asked NATO troops to defend its territory.

---

###### Why do Poland and Lithuania *not* send troops to Ukraine directly?

Because Ukraine has not asked its allies to send troops.
Ukraine is asking for NATO weapons, not for NATO lives.

> "Until the armed conflict on the territory of Ukraine is over, foreign countries will not send their troops into our country," Ukraine’s foreign minister Dmytro Kuleba [explained](https://news.liga.net/en/politics/news/my-i-ne-prosim-kuleba-otvetil-na-predpolojenie-chto-soyuzniki-napravyat-voyska-v-ukrainu).
>
> "Moreover, we are not asking for this, what we are saying is give us weapons, **we know how to fight**."

###### Why does the invitation matter?

Because no foreign troops can enter another sovereign country without the formal invitation (this even applies to military *allies*).
The one who nevertheless does so is called *aggressor state* and ends up with a response like we see the World has against the Russias' armed invasion to Ukraine (2014-2023).

###### Why did Ukraine not ask for troops?

There are various reasons; the most important ones seem to have been discussed in [johnyu's excellent answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/80140/2984).

Subjectively, it seems to me that the most important reason is that involving military personnel to fight in actual battles **can't happen without losses**. These losses may trigger public outcry which, in turn, will lead to calls to withdraw these troops and/or cut Ukraine's support at all.

###### Why do Poland and Lithuania push for NATO membership for Ukraine?

A detailed and informative answer on this topic and its implications was presented in thoughtful answers to this question:

[Why did (most of) the European NATO members support Ukraine's aspirations to joining NATO?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/74034/)

Comment: Has Ukraine actually said they will not allow foreign allied troops into the country? If so, do you have a source?

Comment: @Allure Nothing in the answer talks about "will not allow". The answer said, "it never *asked*" and "never *invited*". These are different verbs.

Comment: Why don't Poland and Lithuania ask then? If they have, do you have a source?

Comment: @Allure Why has Poland and Lithuania {not} asked is a totally different question. I was answering your question in its current form. I hope my answer addresses it completely and in a canonical way.

Comment: I would consider [asking for a no-fly zone](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-60583670) a request for NATO to get involved directly on Ukraine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two very different cases to talk about:

- Lithuania and Poland enters Ukraine now to help against Russia. NATO will not come after them automatically just because they did. NATO has no such a rule as "all attack the enemy that a single member decided to attack". They would need to fight alone with that they have and this is not a lot. If Russia would decide not to escalate, they can simply beat them at the front in Ukraine, NATO will not help.
- Russia attacks Lithuania or Poland, under any various circumstances. This is a different case and NATO should come and help them to drive Russian army outside they territory but not further. In this case they would fight with all NATO assistance available behind that of course will make a huge difference, so much easier to be " psychologically ready" as you say. Again, if Russia would not decide to escalate, they can theoretically call for a peace agreement after the border has been reached.

Both these cases are of course very risky but assuming the rational behavior from both sides, the war should be fought with conventional weapons, at least as long as there is no direct invasion into Russian territory and as long as Russia does attempt to scare the world by the limited nuclear attack (that may provoke the "limited nuclear attack" in response, resulting into nothing good).